# Error in abs(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function R lang

Tags: r

Novice in R, have a problem but don't understand exactly what's wrong with it. Separately code works fine. All together I receive this error

```
 Error in abs(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
In addition: Warning message:
Removed 1 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

**CODE HERE**

```
p + ggtitle("BTC Price Prformance") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="#002D7D", size=14, face="bold", hjust = 0.5)) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="#002D7D", size=14, face="bold", hjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,nrow(mResult)), expand = c(0, 0), breaks = as.numeric(mXLabels[,1]), labels = mXLabels[,2])  + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,max( excelSheet$High[excelSheet$High!=max(excelSheet$High)] )), expand = c(0, 0), breaks=c(0, 2500, 5000, 7500, 10000, 12500, 15000, 17500, 20000)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: Can you pleas show the full code and a sample of data?

Comment: does your data have missing observations i.e. could the `max` be retuning `NA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message says you have missing values. Try

```
your_variable <- na.omit(your_variable)
```

to get a na-free vector.